# String with HTML tags - ng-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm working on an AngularJS Project and I have a JSON file with all my text in it. I have quite a chunk of text inside it with HTML tags like a break. The problem is when I want to display that text inside my html file it display as plain text like: 'this is text (breaktag<>) I want to use'.

This is the code I'm using to display the text inside my HTML file:

```
<p translate="requestGenerator.partnershipGenerationOverview.message"></p>
```

I am using ng-translate.

How can I solve this so that the translate directive uses the HTML tags instead of displaying it with plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-translate provides a post compiling option, which you can either [activate globally](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateProvider#methods_usepostcompiling) or [for specific translations](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.directive:translate).

Enable post compiling globally:

```
app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true);
});
```

Enable post compiling for just this translation:

```
<p translate="requestGenerator.partnershipGenerationOverview.message"
   translate-compile>
</p>
```